# How do I use an image as a submit button?

Tags: html, form-submit, submit-button

Can someone help to change this to incorporate an image called `BUTTON1.JPG` instead of the standard `submit` button?

```
<form id='formName' name='formName' onsubmit='redirect();return false;'>
    <div class="style7">
        <input type='text' id='userInput' name='userInput' value=''>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I was just trying to differentiate from the code. I didn't know they already do that.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use an `image` type input:

```
<input type="image" src="/Button1.jpg" border="0" alt="Submit" />
```

---

The full HTML:

```html
<form id='formName' name='formName' onsubmit='redirect();return false;'>
  <div class="style7">
    <input type='text' id='userInput' name='userInput' value=''>
    <input type="image" name="submit" src="https://jekyllcodex.org/uploads/grumpycat.jpg" border="0" alt="Submit" style="width: 50px;" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Justin, Last question, how do I carry that 'userInput' value into the next page's form so it can be submitted with the next form. I want the value to be hidden.

Comment: That's a really loaded question because I have no idea what programming languages or frameworks you're working with. It's best to post that as a different question and provide that information (e.g., ASP.NET, ASP, PHP, etc.) so someone specialized in that area can help you more thoroughly. But first, I would look around the site to see if the question has been asked before.

Comment: Note that this will behave differently on a form compared to an actual input of type submit under certain conditions.

Comment: Best answer! The official way to make an image submit button. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image

Comment: This will not work if you wish to actually embed an img or svg element.

Comment: This answer should be updated to explain more of the *why*, not just the *how*. As @ArendE pointed out, this is the "official" way to do this. "[`<input>` elements of type image are used to create graphical submit buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image)".

Answer (score 31):

Why not:

```html
<button type="submit">
  <img src="mybutton.jpg" />
</button>
```

Comment: seems better to me since it preserve the essential type of the action triggered by the element

Comment: It is illegal to associate an image map with an IMG that appears as the contents of a BUTTON element.

Comment: thanks lot , stack overflow need one important feature  show correct anser and top up rating show to beging of statting.  this answe really help fulll.  otrher anser can't  so why wast dev time.

Answer (score 10):

Use CSS :

```
input[type=submit] {

background:url("BUTTON1.jpg");

}
```

For HTML :

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" style="background:url("BUTTON1.jpg");">
```

Comment: where do I paste that? what do I need to delete? (I am not a programmer)

Comment: *Observation*: it's not in the long-term best interest of a site full of programmers to teach non-programmers how to survive without hiring programmers...

Comment: hahahahha :P I was also going to post that answer you posted but i thought that it is not a good idea to tell new programmers to use ancient scripts! I know, I was also not a good helper at stacky before when i started it but now i am just better :D

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the border and add a background image in css

Example:

```js
$("#form").on('submit', function() {
   alert($("#submit-icon").val());
});
```

```css
#submit-icon {
  background-image: url("https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/10/18/21/22/california-1751455__340.jpg"); /* Change url to wanted image */
  background-size: cover;
  border: none;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="submit" id="submit-icon" value="test">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form id='formName' name='formName' onsubmit='redirect();return false;'>
        <div class="style7">
    <input type='text' id='userInput' name='userInput' value=''>
    <img src="BUTTON1.JPG" onclick="document.forms['formName'].submit();">
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to make a button in the form of an icon from bootstrap do that:

```
<button type="submit" style="background-color:unset;border:none;">
    <i class="bi bi-person"></i>
    <p style="margin-top:-0.9em;">Logout</p>
</button>
```

Answer (score -4):

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="button">
  <img src="images/free.png" />
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.button {  }
```