# Dropdown menu from Python list using Flask and HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, html-select

I am creating a dropdown menu in HTML using info from a python script. I have inspired myself from this StackOverflow question: [How to create dropdown menu from python list using Flask and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877080/how-to-create-dropdown-menu-from-python-list-using-flask-and-html)

However, when I try to retrieve back the selected answer, I get (also tried with 'colour' and gave me the same problem):

```
select = request.form.get(colours)
NameError: name 'colours' is not defined
```

This is my `__init__.py` which is the main of my Flask application, and I have this route inside which is suppose to retrieve the element that was selected by the dropdown and returns the selected value (simply displayed on the web browser):

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def upload():
if "email" in session:
    if request.method == "POST":
        select = request.form.get(colours)
        return str(select)
    else:
        return render_template("upload.html", colours=dirs)
else:
    return render_template("index.html")
```

This is my `upload.html` which contains the HTML code for the dropdown:

```
 <form  action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="post">

            <div>
                <select class="browser-default custom-select" name= colours method="POST" action="/" >
                    {% for colour in colours %}
                    <option value= "{{colour}}" SELECTED>{{colour}}</option>"
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>

    <input type="image" src="https://thisisapicture.png" style="height: 45px">
</form>
```

How can I retrieve the user's choice for the dropdown as neither request.form.get(colours) and request.form.get(colour) were 'not defined'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="post">
```

Your current `form` tag's action attribute isn't defined so it's not sending data anywhere when you submit it.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake but I still have the same problem even with this

Comment: You're also missing a submit button within the form. How are you submitting it?

Comment: The submit button is suppose to be the image. I inspired myself from this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199788/how-do-i-use-an-image-as-a-submit-button

Comment: Try `select = request.form.get("colours")` to access the form data. Note the "colours" in quotes because you're using it as a key.

Comment: Thank you it was the problem!