# Python Flask Form - html Selectbox returning 'None' as the selected item

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, drop-down-menu

I am creating a website server program with Flask and Python, I am relatively new to Flask. I have created a html form with a Select tag (drop down menu, single select). You can see the code below.

**selectmenu.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form" method="POST" class="selectform">
        <select method="GET" size=5>
            {% for x in options %}
            <option value="{{x}}" SELECTED>{{x}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="go"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Python code for Flask:
**app.py**

```
@app.route('/selectmenu',methods=(['GET','POST']))
def selmenu():
    optionfiles = os.listdir('options')
    form = selectform()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selectedoption = form.selectedoption.data
        print(selectedoption)
        return redirect('/')
    return render_template('selectmenu.html',options=optionfiles,form=form)
```

And finally the Python WTForms classes code **forms.py**:

```
class selectform(FlaskForm):
    optionfiles = os.listdir('userdata')
    print(optionfiles)
    selectedoption = SelectField('selectdropdown', choices=optionfiles,validators=[DataRequired()])
    submitbutton = SubmitField('submit',validators=[DataRequired()])
```

But when the program called `form.selectoption.data` it returns `None` every time.

I have tried many tutorials, and Stackoverflow answers, but still can't get data from the form that isn't `None`.

> NOTE: As you can tell I have uploaded snippets only of the code, as the actual files are all a lot larger! If you need any other bits of the code, e.g: the imports, then please ask, but I am pretty sure the error isn't the imports, for example! Otherwise I would receive an ImportError.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

After finding [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864843/dropdown-menu-from-python-list-using-flask-and-html/62864897#62864897) I found the answer.

I needed to use give the `<select>` tag a name, like this: `name="optionsbox"` in the html file.
Then do `request.form.get("optionsbox")` in the *app.py* file, instead of `form.selectedoption.data`. No changes needed in the *forms.py* file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Flask-WTF (FlaskForm) but the way you write the html part is not compliant with it.
To confirm you can replace `selectmenu.html` by :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.selectedoption() }}
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.submitbutton(class_='btn btn-primary') }}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If it is the case you might have a look at https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html and https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/#forms-in-templates (for the easy template).

(And `return render_template('selectmenu.html',options=optionfiles,form=form)` can be replaced by `return render_template('selectmenu.html',form=form)` )

Comment: Thank you for your answer - the shortening methods were really helpful! But I apologise, I just found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864843/dropdown-menu-from-python-list-using-flask-and-html/62864897#62864897) after doing even more web trawling. Apologies again and thanks for your answer.