# Changing Choose File + Upload File Buttons to Custom Image

Tags: php, html

I would like to change the default buttons made by input type ="file" and button type="submit" to a custom image. I have the buttons linked to a php script that allows the uploaded files to be uploaded to my AWS server.

My code for these buttons are:

```
<form action= "upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit" name="submit"> Upload File </button>
    
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use an image as a submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199788/how-do-i-use-an-image-as-a-submit-button)